# Date archives for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have seen many questions/posts regarding this, but have yet to find a decent solution. Basically I am trying to do what `wp_get_archives` does, but for a custom post type (personally I am unsure why `wp_get_archives` doesn't support custom post types!).

The code I am currently using is as follows

**functions.php**

```
function Cpt_getarchives_where_filter( $where , $r ) {
  $post_type = 'events';
  return str_replace( "post_type = 'post'" , "post_type = '$post_type'" , $where );
}
```

**sidebar-events.php**

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where' , 'Cpt_getarchives_where_filter' , 10 , 2 );
wp_get_archives();
remove_filter('getarchives_where' , 'Cpt_getarchives_where_filter' , 10 );
```

This code displays the dates (e.g. April 2014, March 2014) etc, which is great, but clicking the links just goes to a 404. The URL that is created on each date link is /2014/04/, however it should be something like /events/2014/04/.

Is there any way to include 'events' in the URL so that the archive-events.php template can be used, and is there any reason why the links currently generate a 404?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many examples on the Internet similar as your, but the problem is that although `wp_get_archive()` will create a list of custom post type archives, the links still points to the default post type. This is because Wordpress  do not generate rewrite rules for the archives of the custom post type, you will have to manually create them. Here is an example of how to generate rules for yearly, monthly, and daily archives. It also shows how to convert links with `get_archives_link` filter. Be sure to add `'has_archive' => true` to `register_post_type()` array of arguments and to flush the rewrite rules by visiting the `settings->permalinks` page in admin.

**functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'getarchives_where_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'generate_events_rewrite_rules' );

function getarchives_where_filter( $where, $args ) {

    if ( isset($args['post_type']) ) {      
        $where = "WHERE post_type = '$args[post_type]' AND post_status = 'publish'";
    }

    return $where;
}

function generate_events_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {

    $event_rules = array(
        'events/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=events&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]',
        'events/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=events&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]',
        'events/([0-9]{4})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=events&year=$matches[1]' 
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $event_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

function get_archives_events_link( $link ) {

    return str_replace( get_site_url(), get_site_url() . '/events', $link );

};
```

**sidebar.php examples**

```
add_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'get_archives_events_link', 10, 2 );

wp_get_archives( array( 'post_type' => 'events' ) );            
wp_get_archives( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'type' => 'yearly' ) );
wp_get_archives( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'type' => 'monthly' ) );
wp_get_archives( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'type' => 'daily' ) );

remove_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'get_archives_events_link', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This is brilliant! I spent hours looking for this solution. Thank you.

Comment: Great solutions. Trying to get Taxonomy Term works with date archive, please advise. @Danijel

Comment: There's a paging issue, for example /events/page/2/ returns 404?